# Regularizing a function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I am working on an algorithm that requires derivatives of two functions that I need to take derivative of. Unfortunately they have sharp changes at two points so I have to regularize or smooth-en them before I can take its derivatives.

**First function is**
the Heaviside function

$H(z)=0$ if $z<0$

$H(z)=1$ if $z>=1$

One way to regularize this function is :
$H(z)_{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{2}\left ( 1+\frac{2}{\pi}\left (arctan\left (\frac{z}\epsilon  \right )  \right ){} \right )$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small number close to 1.0

I am having problems dealing with the **Second function**. It is defined as

$\nu(z)=max({0,2|z-0.5|-1})$

A plot of this function is shown below : [image]

As can be clearly seen from the above diagram, there are two sharp changes in the function value for $z=0$ and $z=1$. Please give me ideas how to regularize or smoothen this function.

Please refer to this Chan paper for more details if required.[Chan - Convex Minimization](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~esedoglu/Papers_Preprints/global_chan_esedoglu_nikolova.pdf)

Comment: This [numerical tour](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/numerical-tour/tours/segmentation_4_convex_segmentation/) is relevant.  Note that the numerical tour refers to the same paper you link to.

Comment: A huge thanks to you sir. I am currently reading it and will let you know.

Comment: Sir, it involves a bit of complicated maths which I could not understand. Could you please explain it to me. Perhaps only for the convexification of the Chan Vese model instead of the generalized Mumford Shah model ? Would you please walk through the equations for me ?